# Listview for MenuDrawer is getting rendered differently on different android versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am writing an Android application for Android OS 2.2+.

I have following structure :

> ListView : View that is being used for MenuDrawer
>
> ListAdapter : Adapter which acts as source for ListView

For menu drawer I am using : https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

On **Android 2.2**:
[image: Android 2.2]

On **Android 4.0**:
[image: Android 4.0]

Issue is style for category and title is getting interchanged !!

```
<style name="MenuDrawerCategoryStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/menu_drawer_category_bg</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuDrawerTitleStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

Am I missing something ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. It was related with the technique of caching I was using for inflated views. You have to be careful about using caching in an Adapter. I was caching the element views independent of the style of the element and that was causing issue.